# Call export function that was created inside other function

Tags: function, titanium

I have an export.function that adds a layout to a view and inside that function I have created an other exports. function. Is it somehow possible to call the function that was created inside the first function?

```
exports.AddLayout = function() {

//adds My layout

    exports.UpdateLayout = function() {

    //updates My layout

    };
};
```

Comment: Can you add a code sample to demonstrate what you mean?

Comment: But I solved the problem. Howe I call the second function (UpdateLayout) is exactly the same way I call the AddLayout. There was some problem with the way I was calling the function UpdateLayout